# source files with space in name

Tags: vim

Sometimes I want to use a minimal vim configuration, so with pathogen I have the following alias:

```
alias v='vim -u "$HOME/.vim/simple.vim" --noplugins'
```

and in the simple.vim file I have the following lines:

```
let g:p0 = split(&runtimepath, ',')[0]
exec "source" . g:p0 . "/plugin/NERD_commenter.vim"
```

this fails when `g:p0` contains spaces. I tried

```
exec "source" . "'" . g:p0 . "/plugin/NERD_commenter.vim" . "'"
```

and also

```
exec "source" . '"' . g:p0 . "/plugin/NERD_commenter.vim" . '"'
```

but they both fail. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `fnameescape()` function

```
exec 'source ' . fnameescape(g:p0 . '/plugin/NERD_commenter.vim')
```

Of course, even better would be using the `runtime` command

```
runtime plugin/NERD_commenter.vim
```